# ADFS 3.0 not redirecting on signout

Tags: url, adfs

I have tried the following urls for logout:

https://adfs.example.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https://localhost:32971/
https://adfs.example.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=http://localhost:32971/
https://adfs.example.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0&wreply=https://localhost:32971/
https://adfs.example.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0&wreply=http://localhost:32971/

This is coming from the site http://localhost:32971

On the ADFS side I have the WS-federation Passive Endpoint set as 
https://localhost:32971/

This is also set as the default, so what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @aglasser nope, didn't get any further with it.

Comment: I have had a Microsoft support issue open for over 2 months now and they can't even tell me how to get it working. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string absoluteUrl = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            string replyUrl = absoluteUrl.Substring(0, absoluteUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            var issuer = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer;
            var signOutUrl = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(issuer, null, null);
            WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(signOutUrl), new Uri(replyUrl));
            FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

Try this. Might help.

Comment: why "Like this??" A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Please add some description to make others understand. happy coding :)